# Google analytics API on iOS only gives 24 hours of data?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have a iPad app that use Google analytics.

When user are offline, data stay iPad locally on the "Google database".  And are send the next time app push data when online.

The VERY big problem is that if the data is older that 24 hours, it's just not received at all by analytics!

Have you seen this problem? Any workaround\solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but it's just a suggestion. I've had better luck with Localytics (http://www.localytics.com) than with Google Analytics in iOS apps. You may want to try Localytics instead. (I have no affiliation with either product, I'm just a satisfied Localytics user).

Comment: thanks, but app already ready.  And localytics cost $$.
I just not understand why data lost after 24h, this make no sense... Someone should have advice about this...

Comment: As mentioned above Localytics has a free solution. As to your data loss, it is caused by the fact that web analytics solutions were not designed with offline data in mind so there is typically no mechanism for historical data processing.